# How would time duration and space distance change when we move in the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, reference-frames

It is possible to figure out how time duration and space distance change when we are close to the speed of light - but I am not sure what happens to them if we travel in the speed of light.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47833/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27794/

Comment: Hi time. Welcome to Phys.SE. This post asks hypothetical questions outside accepted standard physics theories, such as, e.g., asking about a massive object traveling at the speed of light. Fictional questions are off-topic, cf. [faq]. If you can modify your question, so it stays within the realm of standard physics, I would be happy to reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible for a massive object to move at the speed of light

see [Accelerating particles to speeds infinitesimally close to the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1557/accelerating-particles-to-the-speed-of-light/1559#1559) for example

so the premise of your question is itself problematic.  When we usually talk about time dilation or length contraction in a moving frame, we are referring to an observer measuring time or length in such a frame, and since it is not possible for an observer to move at the speed of light, it's unclear what the question means in the first place.