# How do photons experience time?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, reference-frames, time, observers

I know that as velocity approaches the speed of light the time dilation shoots to infinity as shown below. [image]

1)So I want to know how time is perceived from the point of view of the photon?

2)Since time stops at the speed of light how do photons move?

3)Is this why photons do not decay or are made up of any smaller particles?

Comment: Photon's don't have a point of view, they aren't conscious.

Comment: Of course but we have some proof as to the nature of light. Is it not possible one can deduce or calculate these characteristics?

Comment: @AlexVoinescu In the frame of reference of the photon, there is no change in time. For the photons, everything is normal. It is our time which stops according to the photons. Not their own.
That should explain part 1 and 2 of your question. Does it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54162/2451

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Photons are absorbed at the same moment they are emitted (as seen from the point of view of the photon.)
2. If you think of things conversely, it is only a massless particle that can experience no lapse of time.  The photon is only able to move at c because it is not moving at all in time.
3. I believe the answer to this question is unrelated.

Comment: What does "from the point of view of the photon" even mean? As far as I know, such a point of view is impossible.