# Can time pass for a photon if it's moving in a medium?

Tags: special-relativity, optics, photons, speed-of-light, refraction

If time does not pass for a photon traveling at the speed of light, which can only occur when traveling in a vacuum, what happens when it is slowed down by traveling through non vacuum space like water, does it time pass for it then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What really cause light/photons to appear slower in media?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11820/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a photon experience space and time?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54162/)