# Moving Through Space-Time

Tags: photons, spacetime

Now see, photons travel through space and they don’t travel through time. And for any particle the limit to travelling through space is $c$. And at that limit it cannot travel through time.

Now my question is, what if we did it’s reverse. I mean the particle is moving more through time and less through space. So does any limit exist for the particle to travel through time? And if such a limit does exist then I guess it must not travel through space.

Is the above scenario possible. And if it is possible then please provide with some examples too.

Thanks in advance!!!

Edit: I have realised that I was talking about a particle at rest. But then I guess no particle is ever at rest. Or is there ? Is there any particle that is at rest from all reference frames, but still exists ?

Comment: Sounds like you're describing a particle at rest.

Comment: Ya but then actually nothing is at rest actually in this universe. Wait I am making an edit in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your first claim needs some clarification. If we pick some reference-frame, and draw a vertical $t$ and horizontal $x$, then light would move through space **and** time- a line with constant slope $c$. What you might mean is that time freezes for the internal clock of the photon. But in our spacetime diagram we still see a curve with slope greater than $c$- the particle "moves through" both space and time.

I'm not sure how you imagine the curve for a object "moving more through time", but I imagine you mean a object whose slope is greater than $c$. This is just what happens for **every** massive object. This will be true in *any* reference frame. The slope might change for a different frame, but it would still be greater than $c$ (this follows from Lorentz transformations).

The jargon is that "a massive object follows a timelike path in spacetime".

Comment: and if I substitute that massive object for a supergiant star or rather I say supermassive black hole then what will happen ?

Comment: The same. **any** massive object.

Comment: Ok thanks for all your help

Comment: *as an object approaches the speed of light, it's proper time vanishes*.  I am currently traveling at $.99999$ times the speed of light (in an appropriately chosen frame), and I don't notice anything odd about my proper time.   See also here:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/451711/4993

Comment: I accept your correction.