# Proper time vs null path

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, observers

I've heard three seemingly contradictory facts, so apparently I'm not understanding at least one of them correctly.

"Proper time along a path is the time elapsed for a clock that travels along that path."

"Proper time along a null path is zero."

"There are no preferred inertial reference frames, so if I travel at the speed of light, my own clock that I take with me will tick like normal for me."

So how can it tick like normal but then not tick at all? Which of these three statements is incorrect?

Comment: The third statement is a physical impossibility, so you should ignore it.

Comment: This may help - [How does a photon experience space and time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54162/37364)

Comment: In relativistic theory (rt), we call the proper time $\tau$ of an object the time measured in “the” frame of reference of this object, that is to say in a frame of reference where it is at rest, but it does not exist this 'rest' reference for a photon, in addition, there is no massive particle which reaches the speed of light in rt.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from one reference frame, you can think about what happens in another reference frame via a [Lorentz transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation).  This is often referred to as a **boost**, because the two frames have different velocities.  There is no inertial reference frame with $v=c$, because there is no Lorentz transformation to connect that frame to any other.  The Lorentz transformation depends on the term $\gamma = (1 - v^2/c^2)^{-1/2}$, which is undefined at $v=c$.

This is related to the fact that nothing can accelerate and reach the speed of light.  Your third statement is conditioned on *if I travel at the speed of light*, but this is impossible. Nothing with mass can travel at the speed of light, so whatever comes after that conditional doesn't matter.