# How can we observe lights properties if it travels at the speed of light, or can we?

Tags: special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, time, reference-frames, photons

Special relativity says that anything moving (almost) at the speed of light will look like its internal clock has (almost) stopped from the perspective of a stationary observer. How do we see light as alternating electric and magnetic fields? Also does light never age?

Comment: Hi Zach. I think the the question has not been *properly* defined. Please have an introductory on Electromagnetism and especially *Maxwell equations*..!

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27794/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54162/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

The time stands still for light indeed, so it will never age.

You can think of the photon as a sine wave shaped electric field fragment traveling at $c$, and you can measure it's amplitude and frequency as it flys past your instrument. The photon itself does not oscillate.

(Bit oversimplified but probably you get the point.)

Comment: +1 this is right but you might want to add how it's the source whose electric and magnetic fields are actually alternating as the photon is produced. Or something like that; just to increase clarity

Comment: @Jim: I think that would cause more confusion, as there is no sine wave shaped things that moving at $c$. Electromagnetic field oscillates locally and this disturbance propagates with $c$. Actually no movement here at all. Waves are tricky... If you can word your suggestion in a non-confusing manner, feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Actually, what you just said to me was exactly what I was trying to suggest to you. Kudos for wording it much better